# Redis | Getting Pipeline result as map of input commands

Tags: redis

I am new to Redis. In my current project  we have extensive use of redis where  we extract 1000+ keys in one go and that too very frequently.

Earlier these calls were sequential which we are trying to replace with pipeline.

We are using Spring RedisTemplate for this purpose.

Now the challenge is that response we get from redisTemplate is list of objects. We want this to map with input keys.

Right now we are dependent on input key order which I dont see very reliable  thing.

Is there any way we can get the same in MAP format for redis itself so that we can user the response directly.

Comment: Why it's unreliable to depend on the input key order?

Comment: Maybe it is. IF there is something better That will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There's no such command. Instead, you can use [Lua scripting](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to achieve the goal. However, **the Lua script also depends on the input key order**.

```
local vals = redis.call('MGET', unpack(KEYS))
local res = {}
for i = 1, #KEYS do
    res[i] = {KEYS[i], vals[i]}
end

return res
```

Test code:

```
redis-cli mset a 1 b 2
OK

redis-cli --eval m.lua a b c ,
1) 1) "a"
   2) "1"
2) 1) "b"
   2) "2"
3) 1) "c"
   2) (nil)
```